# How can I run the YCSB workload on CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb, ycsb

I want to run the "Yahoo! Cloud Serving Benchmark" on CockroachDB for evaluation. Is there a dedicated testing manual or documentation for using YCSB to test CockroachDB?

I tried using the official YCSB workload (https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB), but it did not work. Has CockroachDB made adaptations to it?

Answer (score 0):

CockroachDB has its own own runner for YCSB. It comes in the cockroach binary. You can initialize it using `cockroach workload init ycsb [pgurl...]` and run it using `cockroach workload run ycsb [pgurl...]`.

There is more detailed information about running workloads here https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cockroach-workload.html